# Delta Forward and Put Call Parity

Tags: delta-hedging, delta

Vanilla options are traded interbank with delta hedge. The instrument employed to a delta
hedge is usually a forward with the same expiry (and opposite delta) as the option. This means
that in effect the traded instrument is a call and a put with the same strike.

Why is that so and how does the Put Call Parity fit in here?

Comment: A Call with a certain Delta at time $t_0$ and a Forward with opposite delta is not the same as a Call and a Put with the same strike. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: Since the first bank is already delta hedging the Call and the second bank also plans to delta hedge, it makes sense that the first bank sell the "entire package" consisting of the Call and the forward position that currently hedges it to the second bank. This is the basic logic. Not only does the second bank need both items, but agreeing on a single price for the package is easier than agreeing on 2 prices with 2 counterparties.

Answer (score 1):

If Bank A buys 10mm of a 30 delta call from Bank B, then sells 3mm of the forward to Bank B as a delta hedge, then you can think of the 3mm delta hedge as (short 3mm call plus long 3mm put) using put call parity.  Therefore , the overall trade can be thought of as :  bank A buys 7mm of a call and 3mm of a put at the same strikes from bank B.  Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

- not exactly, a forward is an otc obligation, not an option
- the price of a forward at issuance is 0 by definition
- the parity holds for options only